# How do I open a folder in Textmate with Applescript?

Tags: applescript, textmate

So I've opened Textmate using Applescript, how do I tell it to open a specific folder?

EDIT: Tried Josh K's suggestion, but a strange error occurs. I ran this line:

```
do script "mate rails_projects/newproject"
```

And here is the result:

```
bens-macbook-pro:~ ben$ mate rails_projects/newproject
mate: failed to establish connection with TextMate.
```

But then, in the same console window, I'll type the same line that just failed,

```
bens-macbook-pro:~ ben$ mate rails_projects/newproject
```

and it works. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would point the AppleScript to run the `mate [folder]` command, which will open TextMate with the specified folder.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and got a weird error, which I put into the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing. Here's what I did.

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with objItem in (get selection)
        do shell script "mate " & POSIX path of (objItem as text)
    end repeat
end tell
```

This will look at what files you have selected in the top most Finder window and then open them all in TextMate using the shell command "mate". Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you're not telling AppleScript *exactly* where to find the `mate` command.  Use the full path instead.   Here's a simplified version:

```
set file_path to "/some/path/or/other"
set file_path to POSIX path of file_path
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mate" & file_path
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but there's no need to use the mate utility for this, which may or may not be installed.  The open command will do just fine.  Something like this:

```
do shell script "open -a /Applications/TextMate.app /Path/To/Folder"
```